can I ask about a syndrome from fictional work?
I want to ask about a condition/syndrome that happen in some fictional work and ask if that's syndrome is real or not, and what is the name of it. Can I ask such question here?

You can ask if the syndrome is real, as long as you can describe it clearly and succinctly; you've done your initial research and the answer isn't obvious. An example of a syndrome with an obvious answer would be: "everyone she thinks about for more than 5 minutes suddenly explodes".
